# Check if external database is online

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008

I know that this sentence tells me that 'MyDatabase' database is online:

```
select databasepropertyex('MyDatabase', 'Status')
```

What if I need to check a database from another server? Suppose that I already have a link server, the call should be like this:

```
select databasepropertyex('[192.168.111.33].MyOtherDatabase', 'Status')
```

but it doesn't work, anyone knows how to check this?
Thank you.

Comment: Which platform? Which DB Server? Which environment?

Comment: sorry SQL Server 2008R2 and Windows 2008

Comment: *"I know that this sentence tells me that 'MyDatabase' database is online"* Not exactly. That SQL statement tries to select a particular property of a database. That statement can fail for reasons unrelated to the database's online or offline status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might have to run as a pass through query, e.g.

```
OPENQUERY ( [192.168.111.33] ,'select databasepropertyex(MuOtherDatabase, ''Status'')' )
```

(assuming your already set up linked server is called [192.168.111.33], as implied above - seems like a dubious naming convention to use IPs?)

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you would just try to connect to the database, and trap the error if the connection fails. But depending on your network setup and security, it *might* not be possible to connect directly to the database server.  Exactly how you do that depends on what language and provider you use.

[Some online examples of connection strings>](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

To see whether a SQL Server 2008 database can accept connections, look at the Collation property instead.  I know how strange that sounds, but that's [the documented way](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186823.aspx).

> The ONLINE status may be returned while the database is being opened
>   and is not yet recovered. To identify when a database can accept
>   connections, query the Collation property of DATABASEPROPERTYEX.

For example, many database servers are set up to deny connections from all IP addresses except *one*.  This is especially common in web-based setups; it's a fundamental security measure. In that case connecting like this (immediately below) would work. Code on the application server or web server tries to connect to the database server, and returns an error if it fails.

```
Your server      -->  Application server   -->  Database server
or workstation        or web server
```

But connecting like this won't, because the database server is configured to accept connections only from the application server or web server.

```
Your server      ---------------------------->  Database server
or workstation        
                      Application server
                      or web server
```

Comment: I'm just trying to do it from SQL Server inside a stored procedure